# Convert returned file from server in blob and download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I am trying to covert returned file from server in blob and download it but I am missing smth. file type could be image, pdf or doc.

this is how file response with looks like

[image: response file]

```
$http.get('url', {
     headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).then(function (response) {

    var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image' }),
        url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;

    $scope.fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);

}).catch(function(error) {
});
```

what am I doing wrong and this does not work as expected ?

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: replace `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}` with `responseType:ResponseContentType.Blob`

Comment: gives an error, "ResponseContentType is not defined"

Comment: Okay well try `responseType: 'blob'` instead

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the url directly in an `anchor` tag

```html
<a ng-href="{{url}}" target='_blank'>Download</a>
```

---

If the code above does not work, do this.

```js
function success(response) {
  var data = response.data,
    blob = new Blob([data], {
      type: 'application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8'
    }),
    url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL,
    fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);

  var anchor = document.createElement('a');

  anchor.href = fileUrl;
  anchor.target = '_blank';
  anchor.download = name;
  anchor.style = "display: none";

  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.click();

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
    $window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileUrl);
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: it does not work, file can not be opened...wrong format

Comment: your example downloads file but it can not be opened...format is wrong

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. First convert blob to base64 format

   ```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 

    reader.onloadend = function() {

        var base64data = reader.result; 

        console.log(base64data);
    }
   ```
2. Then use the base64 to download the file

   ```
       downloadFile(base64data, type, fileName) { 

         const file = window.btoa(base64data);

         const url = `data:${fileType};base64,` + file;

         let a = document.createElement('a');

         a.href = url;

         a.download = fileName;

         document.body.appendChild(a);

         a.click();

         document.body.removeChild(a);

         window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

       }
   ```