# How to send a user a downloadable link in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make it to where a user can upload a file to the site and convert their file. Then download it back. I used JavaScripts Web audio api to do so. Now I just need to let the user download the file back. I create a blob but I am currently stuck.

ConverterSec2.jsx:

```
 class ConverterSec2 extends Component {

     render() {
     return (
        <div className="sec2">
            <form>
                <input type="file" id="audio-file" name="file" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/ogg, audio/*" />
                <button type="Submit" id="convert_btn">Convert to 432Hz</button>
                <script src="ihertz_website/src/pages/Converter/compressor.js"></script>
            </form>
        </div>    
    )
}
```

}
export default ConverterSec2

converting.js:

```
//render proccessed audio
offlineAudioCtx.startRendering().then(function(renderBuffer){
make_download(renderBuffer, offlineAudioCtx.length)
    console.log("ERROR: PROCCESSING AUDIO")
})


//download Audio buffer as downloadable WAV file
function make_download(abuffer, total_samples) {
    //get duration and sample rate
    var duration = abuffer.duration,
       rate = abuffer.sampleRate,
       offset = 0;

var new_file = URL.createObjectURL(bufferToWave(abuffer, total_samples));

var download_link = document.getElementById("download_link");
download_link.href = new_file;
var name = generateFileName();
download_link.download = name;
}

//generate name of file
function generateFileName() {
   var origin_name = fileInput.files[0].name;
   var pos = origin_name.lastIndexOf('.');
   var no_exit = origin_name.slice(0, pos);

   return no_exit + ".wav";
  }

//Convert an AudioBuffer to a Blob using WAVE representation
function bufferToWave(abuffer, len) {
    var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
    length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
    buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
    view = new DataView(buffer),
    channels = [], i, sample,
    offset = 0,
    pos = 0;

    //write WAVE header
    setUnit32(0x464664952);
    setUnit32(length - 8);
    setUint32(0x45564157);                         // "WAVE"

    setUint32(0x20746d66);                         // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16);                                 // length = 16
    setUint16(1);                                  // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2);                      // block-align
    setUint16(16);                                 // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)

    setUint32(0x61746164);                         // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(length - pos - 4);                   // chunk length

    // write interleaved data
    for(i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
        channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

    while(pos < length) {
        for(i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {                                        // interleave channels
            sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset]));            // clamp
            sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767)|0;    // scale to 16-bit signed int
            view.setInt16(pos, sample, true);                                   // write 16-bit sample
            pos += 2;
    }
    offset++                                                                          // next source sample
}

//create Blob
return new Blob([buffer], {type: "audio/wav"});


function setUint16(data) {
    view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
    pos += 2;
}

function setUnit32(data) {
    view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
    pos += 4;
}
```

}

Comment: This might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412814/convert-returned-file-from-server-in-blob-and-download

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)